# Check if current window was opened by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window

Is it any way to check, if current window was opened by javascript? I want to determine if current window was opened by `window.open()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check `window.opener` property from child (current) window, check [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) on window.opener